# How to PROPERLY prevent hot-linking with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following line in my .htaccess to prevent direct access to various file types:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com/.*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|css|ini|db|js)$ - [F,NC]
```

and it works, i.e. if I try to access the file http://example.com/test.png it will produce a 403 Forbidden Error page.

BUT,...
I found out that if I type address with a trailing slash (http://example.com/test.png/) it will show the test.png file in the browser. Actually by accessing ANY url of the form http://example.com/test.png/ANYTHING_HERE it will show the test.png in the browser.

Why is that? and how to prevent it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a slash at the end of the request like that, apache will treat that as part of the PATH INFO. For some reason, your server is setup to treat even non-script entities to accept a path after the resource (maybe because of your handler?).

Normally, for a script, if you have a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/path/script.php/this/is/path/info
```

The `script.php` script can access the path info by looking in the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable and see `/this/is/path/info` in it.

Since your images aren't scripts, that part of the path just gets discarded and your image gets served. You'll need to adjust your regex like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com/.*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|css|ini|db|js)(?:/.*|)$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what does the (?:/.*|) part do?

Comment: @cybergeek654 it's just a regex that says either `/.*` or nothing. So you can match stuff that starts with a `/` or nothing at all. It's so you don't end up matching something like `/path/abcd.csstables` or whatever.

Comment: It works. thanks. Though, why I had this problem? should I be concerned and try to fix the source of this problem in my server? What it might be?  Where to look?

Comment: I have another .htaccess within a sub-folder [link](www.example.com/test_folder),  can it be the problem?
the .htaccess in the sub-folder contains the followings:
`code`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
`code`